# nestjs validate hh:mm:ss using class-validator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

In the DB I have a column name time and it's type time,

On my code I'm using nestjs with class-validator and the user send this value for time 10:13:06 ( Assuming it is in 12h format ).

How do I validate this value using class-validator

current code

```
import {
  IsDateString,
  IsNotEmpty,
} from 'class-validator';

export class CreateFilmTime {

  @IsDateString() // O know it's for date string
  time: Date;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use @Matches with a regex like this:

```
  @Matches(/^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$/)
```